# What’s the correct character for the act of showing your teeth?

Tags: characters

The word to show your teeth in Chinese is 呲牙 or 龇牙? I have seen 龇牙 in dictionaries but 呲牙 in like Wechat and other places. So do they have any differences or are they the same?

Comment: Many people use 露齿 to describe grin. For example, "grin with pleasure" means 高兴地露齿而笑.

Answer (score 1):

They are same meaning, just has different written words in some ancient books.
Check the Chinese sentences below:

- 齜牙咧嘴 [教育部重編國語辭典修訂本](http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?ccd=kINxMw&o=e0&sec1=1&op=sid=%22Z00000137351%22.&v=-2)
- 呲牙裂嘴 [教育部重編國語辭典修訂本](http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?ccd=qJD_My&o=e0&sec1=1&op=sid=%22Z00000140430%22.&v=-2)

Answer (score 1):

《现代汉语词典》 lists "呲" as a variant form of "龇".

---

According to 《现代汉语词典》, the official reading of "龇牙" is "zi1ya2", and so does "呲牙" (as a variant form of writing). However, "呲" has another reading "ci1". In my experience, the reading "ci1ya2" for the word is used so common that I only found the official reading when I looked it up in the dictionary. And when you input it with pinyin "ci1ya2" on a computer or phone, you get "呲牙" easily. This may be the reason that you see "呲牙" a lot.

Answer (score 0):

What's the difference between a smile （微笑） and a grimace (龇牙咧嘴)?

There is also 露出 for show your fangs!

她笑了，露出平整、洁白的牙齿。
沃尔什一笑露出了牙齿。

呲牙

> Character decomposition 字形分解 [?]:  Compound 齜
>
> from teeth-chi 齿齒 chǐ and
>
> phonetic this-ci 此 cǐ
>
> simp 龇.

They say it was only pronounced zī, but maybe some people always said cǐ or cī, because of the phonetic component.